# cassandra cpp driver dev 2.9.0-1 wont install on Debian Stretch?

Tags: c++, cassandra, datastax, libssl

I am trying to install the cassandra cpp driver dev 2.9.0-1 on Debian Stretch.

But it depends on libssl.so.1.0.0 & libcrypto.so.1.0.0.

Debian Stretch however only comes with libssl.so.1.0.2?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

It appears Apache Cassandra PHP Driver/Exetension requires OpenSSL v1.0.0 due to the DataStax C/C++ driver dependency for Cassandra

This is for php 7.0 or 7.1 on Debian 9 stretch

the error message you will most likely get is libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found

This workaround works but I do not know if it impacts other dependencies.

mkdir temp
cd temp
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.39_amd64.deb &
ar x libssl1.0.0_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.39_amd64.deb
cp ./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ 
cp ./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
cp -r ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0/ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

service nginx restart
service apache2 restart

To verify the extension is being loaded the following command can be executed:

php -i | grep -A 10 "^cassandra$"